# 2D Array with a custom rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt

I need to create 2d array with 5 rows and 6 columns in the first row and then the rest is 5 columns

so that would look like this

```
{ 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0   }
```

is there any way to do so?

as of now i have only this, it creates 6 rows and 5 columns:

```
private static JButton[][] b = new JButton[6][5];
```

updtae: I am using Java for this.

Comment: You might want to tag this question for the language you're using

Comment: What's the "use case" for this? It might logically lend itself to two arrays: one that is 1x6, and another that's 5x5. Managing it may be simpler as well.

Comment: well, it will be simpler to manage one array in my case.

Comment: @lurker Actually the other would be 4x5, not 5x5. But I agree with the idea of separation.

Comment: @Joffrey yes, sorry, I miscounted. :p

Comment: @user3413705 I don't see how it will be easier in your case. If the first line is different from the others, then you'll probably access it differently anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize your array in 2 steps:

```
// initialize the first dimension
private static JButton[][] b = new JButton[5][];

// initialize the second dimension
static {
    b[0] = new JButton[6];
    for (int i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = new JButton[5];
    }
}
```

When you initialize only the first dimension, it creates an array of rows, in which each row is `null`.

During the second step, you create each row of the desired length.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

You can however, create a 6x6 array and not use the 6th column in every row you don't want to.

```
{ 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 null
  0 0 0 0 0 null
  0 0 0 0 0 null
  0 0 0 0 0 null  }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suit?

```
JButton[][] s = new JButton[5][];
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
    if (i == 0) {
        s[i] = new JButton[6];
    } else {
        s[i] = new JButton[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: Both branches of that if are doing the same thing.

Comment: You did not consider the static context of the variable. Moreover, there is a typo where you probably meant 5 instead of 6.

Comment: Fixed for typo but the other answer deals with the static context.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. Here is my way of doing it:

```
private static JButton[][] b = {{new JButton(), new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() },
        {new JButton(), new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton()}, 
        {new JButton(), new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton()},
        {new JButton(), new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton()},
        {new JButton(), new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton() , new JButton()}};
```

and then I just add them to  a panel

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <b[i].length; j++) {

                panel.add(b[i][j]);

           }

        }
```

Comment: "your way" is really painful to use, what if you had a 256*256 array? Copy paste?